# Mercurial authorization failure after sending data

Tags: apache2, mercurial

I need some help solving a bit of a tough issue i have been having with Mercurial and pushing data over HTTP/HTTPs for the past few days. Initially I tried setting this up as just HTTP, but kept getting the response back that it required SSL, and enabled that. Now, I am getting an authorization failed message. The repository i am attempting to push to does not have authentication required. Here is a paste bin with the logs and a snippet of the configuration. https://pastebin.com/ypLGZnzM

How can i fix this? I've really been stuck on this for a few days now and just don't know what else to do but ask here. I've tried searching and no similar issues have been asked.

Answer (score 0):

The answer was to add the lines:

```
push_ssl = false
allow_push = *
```

Since the apache configuration handles who is allowed into which repository. This handles everything needed. If somebody can tell me how to make the server work over SSL. Then i would be very grateful. But for now, it works over non-SSL with this change to hgweb.config.